# Link css filename with hash to index.html after the Extract Text Plugin

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

I would like to ask how can I link the generated css files with a hash name to my index.html after I run the npm for my production:

```
"build-production": "webpack -p --progress --colors --config webpack.config.production.js"
```

This is the plugin in my webpack config that will generate the filename with hash since every time I build for production it generates a new hash filename. Is there a way that can automatically do it without manually editting the index.html?

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name][contenthash].css")
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) is the answer.

It can automatically add `link` and `script` tag to `index.html` for generated css and js file.

Comment: It's not the answer if html generates by server in runtime.

Comment: @Jonik and what is the answer then ? ;)

Comment: @Jonik, posted an answer based on your mention

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for the case of generating html by server (Node.js) in runtime, mentioned by @Jonik above.

For development:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const webpackConfig = require('../../internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel');

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const middleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  silent: true,
  stats: 'errors-only',
});

const fileSystem = middleware.fileSystem;
const encoding = 'utf-8';
const outputPath = compiler.outputPath;
```

For production:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path= require('path');

const fileSystem = fs;
const encoding = { encoding: 'utf-8' };
const outputPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build');
```

And then:

```
let style = '';
fileSystem.readdirSync(outputPath).forEach((file) => {
  if (file.indexOf('.css') !== -1) {
    style += fileSystem.readFileSync(`${outputPath}/${file}`, encoding);
  }
});
```

The 'style' variable will contain your css bundled by ExtractTextPlugin.